# Одно и то же - член предложения

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

<...> : не то дождь, не то мгла, а впрочем, в сущности, одно и то же.
Чем является "одно и то же"? СИС в неполном двусоставном предложении (отсутствующее подлежащее - "это")?

Comment: Да, Вы полностью правы.

Comment: Как мне кажется, сокращенный вариант предложения неправильно составлен, в полном тексте имеется в виду, что мга и мгла - это одно и то же. "Что-то сочится все время сверху: не то дождь, не то, как издавна называли здесь жители, мга — слово, явно же не случайно совпадающее с другим словом — мгла, а впрочем, в сущности это одно и то же…https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=178366&p=29 С другой стороны, у автора неудачно поставлены два тире, что затрудняет понимание текста.

Comment: Sharon, вы правы, я многое опустила для упрощения понимания, к тому же в учебнике оно уже было в измененном виде, но я подумала, что мга/мгла и дождь к сути моего вопроса не относятся)

Бот Ботович, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[одно́ и то́ же](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/201818/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE) — *местоимение*. То же самое.
Это устойчивое сочетание, которое используется в качестве указательного местоимения.

**Это** [есть] **одно и то же.**
В этом предложении "одно и то же" — составное именное сказуемое, в котором пропущен вспомогательный глагол-связка.
[Составное именное сказуемое](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/704-15_sostavnoe_imennoe_skazuemoe.html)

Рассмотреть однозначно ваше исковерканное предложение нет возможности (смысл искажен).
Для правильного синтаксического разбора предложение необходимо целиком.

Оригинал выглядит так.
*Что-то сочится все время сверху: не то дождь, не то, как издавна называли здесь жители, мга — слово, явно же не случайно совпадающее с другим словом — мгла, а, впрочем, в сущности это одно и то же...* ([А. Калинин. Возврата нет)](https://www.rulit.me/books/vozvrata-net-surovoe-pole-eho-vojny-vozvrata-net-read-178185-29.html)

Comment: Большое спасибо!